# Mi aplicación python con kivy para android no obtiene permisos

Tags: python, android, kivy

Por mucho que lo he intentado no consigo que durante la instalación de mi programa este te pida permisos para poder almacenar y leer archivos. Ni tampoco acceso a internet.

Y como la aplicación almacena los datos con sqlite en el dispositivo crashea desde el primer instante.

Además he intentado hacer uso de unas instrucciones que piden permisos durante la ejecución del programa, pero ni aún así:

request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ])texto en negrita

Además cuando el usuario tiene que elegir un archivo el selector de archivos no muestra nada.

Incluso en el fichero spec especifiqué como te dice la documentación de buildozer los permisos necesarios:

**android.permissions = INTERNET,MANAGE_MEDIA,MANAGE_DOCUMENTS**

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar los permisos a tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Eso era lo que encontré para Android Studio pero yo programo con Kivy en python. Aún así muchas gracias.